# TwitchIO bot without blocking

Tags: python, twitch, twitch-api

I'd like to use TwitchIO to talk to Twitch chat inside another program, without needing to hijack the main loop with Bot's run().

The official documentation here (https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) shows the code being run like:

```
from twitchio.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise our Bot with our access token, prefix and a list of channels to join on boot...
        # prefix can be a callable, which returns a list of strings or a string...
        # initial_channels can also be a callable which returns a list of strings...
        super().__init__(token='ACCESS_TOKEN', prefix='?', initial_channels=['...'])

    async def event_ready(self):
        # Notify us when everything is ready!
        # We are logged in and ready to chat and use commands...
        print(f'Logged in as | {self.nick}')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        # Here we have a command hello, we can invoke our command with our prefix and command name
        # e.g ?hello
        # We can also give our commands aliases (different names) to invoke with.

        # Send a hello back!
        # Sending a reply back to the channel is easy... Below is an example.
        await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.name}!')


bot = Bot()
bot.run()
# bot.run() is blocking and will stop execution of any below code here until stopped or closed.
```

But as that last line says, run() will block execution.

Is there some other way of running it that doesn't block? Something like (made up)

`bot.poll()`

That would need to be run periodically in my program's main loop?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding any more code that uses the Bot class? If not I would suggest just making 2 processes.

The simplest way to do this is just creating 2 python files and running both of them at the same time.

If you really must run them both on the same program I would look into parallel processing. The next time you post a question I would suggest putting that "other programs" code into the question so people don't have to make those assumptions.

#ps if you need to run them in the same program edit your question to show the code you need to run together and ill take another look

Comment: "Need" is a strong word. :) It just felt like a waste to run them in two totally separate processes and communicate via IPC just because the API doesn't support a nonblocking mode? But I agree that it looks like this might be the only way.

Comment: Oh, and I didn't include the other code because it's a whole program with like ~10k LoC. With its own blocking main loop.